# NativeScript: flipping a boolean value via "!" in the mustache syntax i.e. {{ !true }}

Tags: javascript, css, xml, nativescript

I'm having problems disabling a button via its `isEnabled` property using the mustache syntax. Here's roughly what the XML looks like (simplified):

```
<Page loaded="onLoad">
    <StackLayout>
        <Button class="btn" isEnabled="{{ !isBusy }}"/>
        <ActivityIndicator busy="{{ isBusy }}"/>
    </StackLayout>
</Page>
```

I can successfully show the `ActivityIndicator` when setting `isBusy` to `true` in the observable, however the `:disabled` style is not applied to my button. This is what the CSS looks like, the button should turn from bright red to grey:

```
.btn {
    color: #FF0000;
    border-color: #FF0000;
}

.btn:disabled {
    color: #888888;
    border-color: #888888;
}
```

And finally my JS Code looks like this. `isBusy` is created implicitly by setting it to `true`, this works since the Indicator is showing when it should.

```
const observable = require("tns-core-modules/data/observable");
const ObservableArray = require("tns-core-modules/data/observable-array").ObservableArray;

var someArray = new ObservableArray([]);

var pageData = observable.fromObject({
    listItems: someArray,
});

exports.onLoad = function (args) {
    const page = args.object;
    page.bindingContext = pageData;
    doSomething();
}

function doSomething () {
    pageData.set("isBusy", true);
    // doing something that takes some time
    pageData.set("isBusy", false);
}
```

I suspect that the `{{ !isBusy }}` syntax is wrong, which is odd because it was working earlier. I updated my dependencies from NativeScript 4.x to 5.0 recenty, maybe that has something to do with the issue?

(The `ObservableArray` is part of my `pageData` because I'm dynamically updating a list that I need to fill, that is working as intended as well ...)

Comment: have you tried `{{isBusy != true}}`?

Comment: Did you try setting a initial value for `isBusy` inside the fromObject call?

Comment: @Manoj that did it! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Manoj's answer worked.

In my JS file I had to initialize `isBusy`:

```
var pageData = observable.fromObject({
    listItems: someArray,
    isBusy: false
});
```

Thanks again!